# Slicing python matrix into quadrants

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

Suppose I have the following matrix in python:

`[[1,2,3,4],
 [5,6,7,8],
 [9,10,11,12],
 [13,14,15,16]]`

I want to slice it into the following matrices (or quadrants/corners):

```
[[1,2], [5,6]]

[[3,4], [7,8]]

[[9,10], [13,14]]

[[11,12], [15,16]]
```

Is this supported with standard slicing operators in python or is it necessary to use an extended library like numpy?

Comment: If you're needing to do this, I think you probably _should_ be using numpy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are always working with a 4x4 matrix:

```
a = [[1 ,2 , 3, 4],
     [5 ,6 , 7, 8],
     [9 ,10,11,12],
     [13,14,15,16]]

top_left =  [a[0][:2], a[1][:2]]
top_right = [a[0][2:], a[1][2:]]
bot_left =  [a[2][:2], a[3][:2]]
bot_right = [a[2][2:], a[3][2:]]
```

You could also do the same for an arbitrary size matrix:

```
h = len(a)
w = len(a[1])
top_left =  [a[i][:w // 2] for i in range(h // 2)]
top_right = [a[i][w // 2:] for i in range(h // 2)]
bot_left =  [a[i][:w // 2] for i in range(h // 2, h)]
bot_right = [a[i][w // 2:] for i in range(h // 2, h)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is already answered, but I think this solution is more general. 
It can also be used `numpy.split` and list comprehension in the following way:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])
B = [M for SubA in np.split(A,2, axis = 0) for M in np.split(SubA,2, axis = 1)]
```

Getting:

```
>>>[array([[1, 2],[5, 6]]), 
array([[3, 4],[7, 8]]), 
array([[ 9, 10],[13, 14]]),
array([[11, 12],[15, 16]])]
```

Now if you want to have them assigned into different variables, just:

```
C1,C2,C3,C4 = B
```

Have a look to [numpy.split doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html). 
Changing the parameter `indices_or_sections` you can get a higher number of splits.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16]]
>>> x = map(lambda x:x[:2], a)
>>> x
[[1, 2], [5, 6], [9, 10], [13, 14]]
>>> y = map(lambda x: x[2:], a)
>>> y
[[3, 4], [7, 8], [11, 12], [15, 16]]
>>> x[:2] + y[:2] + x[2:] + y[2:]
[[1, 2], [5, 6], [3, 4], [7, 8], [9, 10], [13, 14], [11, 12], [15, 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the answers can provide the required solution. These are **not** applicable for the arrays in different sizes. If you have a NumPy array in size of (6x7), then these methods will not create a solution. I have prepared a solution for myself and want to share it here.

Note: In my solution, there will be overlaps due to the different axis sizes. 
I have created this solution to divide an astronomical image into four quadrants. I, then, use these quadrants to calculate the mean and median in an annulus.

```
import numpy as np
def quadrant_split2d(array):
    """Example function for identifiying the elements of quadrants in an array.
    array: 
        A 2D NumPy array.
    Returns:
        The quadrants. True for the members of the quadrants, False otherwise.
    """
    Ysize = array.shape[0]
    Xsize = array.shape[1]
    y, x = np.indices((Ysize,Xsize))
    if not (Xsize==Ysize)&(Xsize % 2 == 0): print ('There will be overlaps')
    sector1=(x<Xsize/2)&(y<Ysize/2)
    sector2=(x>Xsize/2-1)&(y<Ysize/2)
    sector3=(x<Xsize/2)&(y>Ysize/2-1)
    sector4=(x>Xsize/2-1)&(y>Ysize/2-1)
    sectors=(sector1,sector2,sector3,sector4)
    return sectors
```

You can test the function with the different type of arrays. 
For example:

```
test = np.arange(42).reshape(6,7)
print ('Original array:\n', test)
sectors = quadrant_split2d(test)
print ('Sectors:')
for ss in sectors: print (test[ss])
```

This will give us the following sectors:

```
[ 0  1  2  3  7  8  9 10 14 15 16 17]
[ 3  4  5  6 10 11 12 13 17 18 19 20]
[21 22 23 24 28 29 30 31 35 36 37 38]
[24 25 26 27 31 32 33 34 38 39 40 41]
```